# Laravel routing 404 error not found

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes

So I am learning Laravel in order to make my website more user friendly, I am currently in the process of watching YouTube videos in order to learn Laravel and whilst on this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJNKc7GWiAI) I can't seem to access a route.

**routes.php**

```
<?php

Route::get('/', array (
'as' => 'home',
'uses' => 'HomeController@home'
));

/*
Unauthenticated group/not logged in
*/

Route::group(array('before' => 'guest'), function() {

/*
CSRF protection group
*/

Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function() {

});

/*
Create account (GET)
*/
Route::get('/account/create', array (
'as' => 'account-create',
'uses' => 'AccountController@home'
));
});
```

**Account Controller**

```
<?php
class AccountController extends BaseController {

    public function getCreate() {

    }

    public function postCreate() {

    }


}
```

**Error message**

The requested URL /laravel/login/public/account/create was not found on this server.

The local site is in C:\wamp\www\laravel\login

EDIT:
I also uploaded the file to a web server and still not working. here's the url.

```
http://178.62.98.162/laravel/login/public/account/create
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.htaccess` file is not present at your public folder

or

your server is not configured to use it

Comment: I have a .htaccess file in the public folder, here is the code.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: you need to enable .htaccess in your server.
[link](http://tildemark.com/enable-htaccess-on-apache/)

Comment: Worked a charm! Thanks so much. I would upvote but currently cannot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all edit your root directory in WAMP to laravel/login/public so that you need not to add public in the urls everytime for the same edit the httpd.conf file and/or the vhosts.conf file for the site you wish to change. The Directory directive will let you specify where the
files for this site are to be located. Click on the Wamp icon on the left hand side and go through apache/httpd settings and you will get it.